# Why Dynamic lookup transforamtion in informatica supports only equality condition?

Tags: informatica

hiee Friends,
I want to know why dynamic lookup transformation in informatica supports only Equality condition.It is not supporting any other condition.I tried it and I am getting an error while using condition other than Equality. If any one knows please tell me

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic lookup is a cached version of the data trickling through it so that you can refer to that data at a point in time by referencing the lookup cache which was created by the dynamic lookup later rather than using a separate cached lookup to the source database which would be far more costly and as a snapshot, not representative of the current data. If you were to update more than one record in the cache based on each record passing through then the lookup cache would no longer be representative of the source data but instead be some pseudo target table which it was never intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup transformation has :

> - Greater than
> - Less than
> - Equal
> - Not Equal

You could use Lookup Transformation if you needed one of conditions that I mentioned above. Good luck!